# How to store an Image as a 1*n floating point vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Im trying to obtain a single floating vector called testdata  from images obtained via a webcam.Once the images are converted to a single floating vector ,it is  passed to a trained Neural Network.To test the network I use the function  float CvANN_MLP::predict(const Mat& inputs, Mat& outputs).This function requires an testing sample in the format as follows :-

Floating-point matrix of input vectors, one vector per row.

testdata vector is defined as follows:-

```
// define testing data storage matrices
//NumberOfTestingSamples is 1 and AttributesPerSample is number of rows *number of columns

Mat testing_data = Mat(NumberOfTestingSamples, AttributesPerSample, CV_32FC1);
```

To store each row of the image in a CSV Format ,I do the following :-

```
Formatted row0= format(Image.row(0),"CSV" ); //Get all rows to store in a single vector
Formatted row1= format(Image.row(1),"CSV" ); //Get all rows to store in a single vector
Formatted row2= format(Image.row(2),"CSV" ); //Get all rows to store in a single vector
Formatted row3= format(Image.row(3),"CSV" ); //Get all rows to store in a single vector
```

I then output all formated rows which were stored in row0 to row3 into a textfile as such:-

```
store_in_file<<row0<<", "<<row1<<", "<<row2<<", "<<row3<<endl;
```

This will store the entire Mat on a single line.

The textfile is closed .I reopen the same textfile to extract the data to store into the vector testdata

```
 // if we can't read the input file then return 0

 FILE* Loadpixel = fopen( "txtFileValue.txt", "r" );

 if(!Loadpixel) // file didn't open
{
    cout<<"ERROR: cannot read file \n";
    return 0; // all not OK;
}
for(int attribute = 0; attribute < AttributesPerSample; attribute++)
{
            fscanf(Loadpixel, "%f,",&colour_value);//Reads a single attribute and stores it in colour_value
            testdata.at<float>(0, attribute) = colour_value;
}
```

This works ,however after a period of time the file doesn't open and displays the Error Message:"ERROR: cannot read file ".There is alot of limitation to this method,unnecessary time take to store in a textfile and then reopen and extract.What is the best way to store an image(Mat) into a single floating point vector similar to `testdata.at<float>(0, attribute)` ? Or is there a simple way to ensure that the file always opens,basically the correct the problem?

Comment: You might want to clarify what `Formatted` and `Image` are.

Comment: You do realize that what you wrote may make sense in your head, but is completely oscure to anybody else? Put some context for it, describe what these "vectors" are, provide declarations for  used variables, describe the "big picture" of your problem.

Comment: I have just uppdated the question posted to explain what Im achieving in greater detail,hope this helps.The variable "Image"  is a Mat obtained from the webcam.Using opencv, a Mat can be converted from default Format to a CSV Format by using:-   Formatted row0= format(Image.row(0),"CSV" );

Comment: Any idea why the file opens for more than a 1000 times and then cant open?Is there a way to correct this,if not what is the best alternative?

Comment: My crystal ball says you are missing fclose, hence you are out of file descriptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sane solution is of course to convert the values directly in memory. The whole file intermediate is an incredible kludge, as you suspected.

If you would use standard C++ types such as `std::vector`, we could provide actual code. The simple algorithm equivalent to your code is to just iterate through your 2D image one pixel at a time, and append each pixel's value to the back of the 1D vector.

However, that's a bad idea for neural network processing of webcam images anyway. If your input shifts down by a single pixel - entirely possible - the whole 1D vector changes. It's therefore advisable to normalize your input first. That may require translating, scaling and rotating the image first.

[edit]
Standard C++ example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Image2D;
std::vector<float> Vector1D;
for (auto const& row : Image2D) {
  for (auto pixel : row) { 
    Vector1D.push_back(pixel);
  }
}
```

Comment: The images are cropped to a standard size then normalize ,equalize and converted to binary images.This process is correct and predicts fine,problem is after a certain number of images the file doesn't open, I do not want to use the textfile to obtain the float vector of an Image.May you please,elaborate more on your suggested method by provide an example?